# Logical next step in Django newsfeed web app

Tags: python, beginner, api, django

I'm hoping to get feedback on my current code from someone more experienced in Django, and in the concepts I'm trying to implement. Let me preface by saying that I am a novice to Django. This is my first time using the framework.

Here's the gist of my goals in my project:

- Create a web application that displays reddit posts and tweets in a 'newsfeed' like format.

***What I've done:***

- Create a services.py script that fetches the data from reddit and twitter from their API's using PRAW and Tweepy libraries respectively.
- Grab each post from either reddit or twitter, and store in a collective list, ordered by earliest creation time first.
- Pass this list through the view as context to the page template (joke.html, sorry for the unconventional naming).
- In the template, loop through the context, check if the item is a reddit or twitter post. Then pass the list item into the respective template tag. (I have two template tags which essentially spit out proper HTML to embed either a reddit or twitter post onto the page).

Basically, is it possible to implement this newsfeed-esque design using Django, or does that reach the limit of the framework's functionality? Right now, the posts are being embedded onto the page, but there isn't a cache of previous posts, nor does the 'feed' update based on scrolling.

The template is in `joke.html`, the function in `views.py`, API fetching and post sorting (on creation date) in `services.py`.

#### joke.html

```
{% block content %}{% load reddit_tag_test %} {% load tweet_tags %} {% autoescape off %}
   {% for item in connects %}
     <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline">
       {% if item|first in 'm' %}
         {% reddit_tag_test item %}
       {% else %}
         {% tweet_tags item %}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} {% endautoescape %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
     <script async src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
     <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

#### views.py

```
def joke(request):

    connects = services.connections()

    return render(request, 'joke.html', dict(connects=connects))
```

#### services.py

```
sources = {}

def tweet_connect(key, secret, access_key, access_secret):

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key, secret)

    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

    t_post_dict = {}

    my_timeline = api.home_timeline(count=5)

    current_status = []

    default = 'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/'

    for status in my_timeline:
        if status.id not in db:
            db.append(status.id)
            url = default + str(status.id)
            t_post_dict[url] = str(status.created_at)
            current_status.append(url)

    return t_post_dict  

def reddit_connect(client_id, secret, username, password, user_agent):

    sub = 'nba'

    r_post_dict = {}

    reddit = praw.Reddit(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=secret,
        username=username,
        password=password,
        user_agent=user_agent)

    id_list = []

    for r in reddit.subreddit(sub).new(limit=9):
        time = r.created
        dt_str = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time))
        r_post_dict[r.id] = dt_str
        id_list.append(r.id)

    return r_post_dict

sources['twitter'] = tweet_result
sources['reddit'] = red_result

def connections():

    time_assoc_dict = {}
    times = []
    src = []

    for keys, value in sources.items():
        for k, v in value.items():
            time_posted = v
            source = k
            time_assoc_dict[source] = time_posted
            times.append(time_posted)

    for post in times:
        newest_post = min(times)  # find the newest post
        times.remove(newest_post)  # remove it from the list
        for k, v in time_assoc_dict.items():
            if newest_post == v:
                src.append(k)

    src = src[::-1]

    return src
```

P.S. I know Stack Exchange mentions that I shouldn't ask how to implement new features. I am looking for genuine feedback on my code, and improvements I can make. I am obviously open to suggestions on what to do next, because I would like to learn how to cache previous posts (lets say I kept scrolling down the page), but it is not expected. If I only receive feedback, I will be more than satisfied.